# Dir-610 router won't accept connection until restart

Tags: wireless-networking, router

My DIR-610 randomly drops connection for computers on the network.

If you try to connect to it again (wireless), windows says it's Unable to connect.

When this happens you can either wait until sometime it works again, or just unplug/plug the power for DIR-610, then it works fine.

I think it has something to do with IP Assignment or something like that.

What could it be? How can I debug and fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: That Home-Office Network device is so sensitive with hight temperature, so an option is cause your device haves an a malfunction for hardware degradation.

Comment: My linksys router does the exact same thing. I had to upgrade the firmware to fix this. I'm certain it has nothing to do with IP assignment.